# dropdownlist returning null value to my controllers action result

Tags: vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am new to MVC and have looked through a great number of these posts and have not been able to solve my problem.

I have successfully populated my drop down list using a dropdownlistfor html helper, however when I submit the form the selected items value is not being passed with the model into the action result.  In other words when I debug and examine the values the property for the dropdownlist is nothing.  I believe that this is causing the "ModelState.isValid" to return false as well.

Here is my Model:

```
    Public Class Warranty

        Public Property state As DropDownList

        Private _States As IEnumerable(Of State)
        Public Property States As IEnumerable(Of State)
            Get
                If _States Is Nothing Then
                    _States = GetStates()
                End If
                Return _States
            End Get
            Set(value As IEnumerable(Of State))
                _States = value
            End Set
         End Property

        Public Shared Function GetStates() As List(Of State)
            Dim l As New List(Of State)
            l.Add(New State With {.Value = "none", .Text = "Selected One"})
            l.Add(New State With {.Value = "UT", .Text = "Utah"})
            l.Add(New State With {.Value = "NV", .Text = "Nevada"})
            Return l
        End Function
    End Class
```

Here is my State Class:

```
    Public Class State

        Public Property Value As String
        Public Property Text As String
    End Class
```

Here are my controller methods:

```
    ' GET: /Warranty
    Function WarrantyRegistration() As ActionResult
        ViewData("Message") = "Warranty Registration Form"
        Dim _statesList As New SoleWebSite.Models.Warranty
        Return View(_statesList)
    End Function

    '

    'POST: /Warranty
    <HttpPost()> _
    Function WarrantyRegistration(ByVal warranty As SoleWebSite.Models.Warranty) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then

            war.state = warranty.state.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()
            //  warranty.state



            db.AddTowarranty_registrations(war)
            db.SaveChanges()
            db.Dispose()

            Return RedirectToAction("WarrantyRegistration")
        End If
        Return View(warranty)
    End Function
```

Here is my view:

```
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.state, New SelectList(Model.States, "Value", "Text"))</td>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I would like to keep everything strongly typed and avoid using viewbag or viewdata if possible.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if the viewstate enabled

Comment: @Waleed A.K., ViewState? In an ASP.NET MVC application? Not only that it is not enabled but such thing doesn't even exist :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected value property should be a simple scalar type such as `String` or `Integer` and not a complex type such as [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx). By the way the DropDownList type is a classic WebForms server side control that has absolutely nothing to do in an ASP.NET MVC application. You should get rid of absolutely any reference to the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace in an ASP.NET MVC application. So in your `Warranty` use a simple type:

```
Public Property state As String
```

and in your POST action you simply read the value:

```
<HttpPost()> _
Function WarrantyRegistration(ByVal warranty As SoleWebSite.Models.Warranty) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        war.state = warranty.state
        //  warranty.state
        db.AddTowarranty_registrations(war)
        db.SaveChanges()
        db.Dispose()
        Return RedirectToAction("WarrantyRegistration")
    End If
    Return View(warranty)
End Function
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  Thanks for your quick response.